# This fell off of my 02 clk430 and have no idea WTF it is

Tags: mercedes-benz

[image]

Driving Home, and this randomly fell off of my car, have no idea as to what it is, can anyone help me?

Comment: Pictures from different angles may help...

Comment: Looks like a motor mount, transmission mount or muffler stabilizer to me

Comment: Are you sure it fell off your car? One time I ran over a piece of another car and thought it was from mine.

Comment: How do I upload more images?

Comment: Use the "edit" button at the left bottom of your question, then the little picture icon above the enter text box.

Comment: As @GdD mentions it might not really be from your car.  If it is, you don't want to drive the car until you fix it. That is a heavy peace of steel, it should be holding something important from moving.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a transmission mount or motor mount off a Mercedes clk430 - so you're safe there. Here's what they look like;

[image]

Your best approach would be to drive to a mechanic, get it up on ramps, and see if the mechanic can spot anything missing or damaged.